# Springboot 2.0/Camel/Active MQ throwing exception with ActiveMQComponent / ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

A simple listener project using Spring boot, camel & apache active MQ (POM below) is throwing below build error.

When org.apache.activemq: activemq-camel dependency is used directly (in place of spring-boot-starter-activemq), then there is exception with resolving ActiveMQConnectionFactory [exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory], class is getting looked up with incorrect package name (‘spring’ in between).

```
[ERROR] /D:/2  Technology/6. Java/Source/HandsOnLab/HelloCamel-1/src/main/java/com/handson/camelservice/QueueConfiguration.java:[4,43] package org.apache.activemq.camel.component does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/2  Technology/6. Java/Source/HandsOnLab/HelloCamel-1/src/main/java/com/handson/camelservice/QueueConfiguration.java:[12,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ActiveMQComponent
  location: class com.handson.camelservice.QueueConfiguration
[ERROR] /D:/2  Technology/6. Java/Source/HandsOnLab/HelloCamel-1/src/main/java/com/handson/camelservice/QueueConfiguration.java:[23,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ActiveMQComponent
  location: class com.handson.camelservice.QueueConfiguration
[ERROR] /D:/2  Technology/6. Java/Source/HandsOnLab/HelloCamel-1/src/main/java/com/handson/camelservice/QueueConfiguration.java:[23,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ActiveMQComponent
  location: class com.handson.camelservice.QueueConfiguration
```

Configuration class source code below:

```
@Component
public class QueueConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQComponent activeMQConsumer() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
        activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);
        return activeMQComponent;
    }   

}
```

POM file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You need camel-jms-starter and also the activemq-camel dependency in your POM file.

Comment: Thanks. Added activemq-camel dependency and code works fine